# Unpredictable SIGSEGV (runtime error) in code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, fibonacci

I have written a code which calculates Fibonacci number using my own arbitrary precision functions for multiplication and addition.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<map>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

#define max 3000

struct data_type{
   int string[max]; 
};

struct data_type mul(struct data_type a,struct data_type b) {
   struct data_type c;
   memset(c.string,0,sizeof(int)*max);
   int k;
   int i,j;
   for(i=max-1;i>0;i--) {
      int num=a.string[i];
      int carry=0;
      int rem=0;
      k=i;

      for(j=max-1;j>0;j--) {
         int n=b.string[j]*num + carry;
         int r=n%10;
         carry=n/10;
         int p=(c.string[k]+r+rem)%10;
         rem=(c.string[k]+r+rem)/10;
         c.string[k]=p;  
         k--;
      }
   }

   return c;
}

struct data_type add(struct data_type a,struct data_type b) {
   struct data_type c;
   memset(c.string,0,sizeof(int)*max);
   int carry=0;
   int i,j;
   int k=max-1;

   for(i=max-1,j=max-1;i>0 && j>0;i--,j--) {
      int res=(a.string[i] + b.string[j])+carry;
      carry=res/10;
      c.string[k--]=res%10;
   }

   return c;
}

void multiply(struct data_type f[2][2],struct data_type m[2][2]){

   struct data_type x,y,z,t;
   x=add(mul(f[0][0],m[0][0]),mul(f[0][1],m[1][0]));    
   y=add(mul(f[0][0],m[0][1]),mul(f[0][1],m[1][1]));    
   z=add(mul(f[1][0],m[0][0]),mul(f[1][1],m[1][0]));    
   t=add(mul(f[1][0],m[0][1]),mul(f[1][1],m[1][1]));    

   f[0][0]=x;
   f[0][1]=y;
   f[1][0]=z;
   f[1][1]=t;       
}

void power(struct data_type f[2][2],unsigned long long n){

   if((n==0)||(n==1))
      return ;
   struct data_type a,b;
   memset(a.string,0,sizeof(int)*max);
   memset(b.string,0,sizeof(int)*max);
   a.string[max-1]=1;
   b.string[max-1]=0;
   struct data_type m[2][2]={{a,a},{a,b}};  

   power(f,n/2);

   multiply(f,f);

   if(n%2 != 0)
       multiply(f,m);
   }

   struct data_type fib(unsigned long long n){
   struct data_type a,b;
   memset(a.string,0,sizeof(int)*max);
   memset(b.string,0,sizeof(int)*max);
   a.string[max-1]=1;
   b.string[max-1]=0;

   struct data_type f[2][2]={{a,a},{a,b}};

   if(n==0)
      return b;

   power(f,n-1);
   return f[0][0];
}

int main()
{   
   int t;
   cin>>t;

   for(int w=0;w<t;w++){
      unsigned long long n;
      cin>>n;
      struct data_type a,b,c;

      a=fib(n-1);
      b=fib(n+2);
      c=add(a,b);

      int ck=0;

      for(int i=0;i<max;i++) {
         if(c.string[i] && !ck)
            ck=1;

         if(ck)
            cout<<c.string[i];
      }

      cout<<"\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

My problem is that it's showing SIGSEGV on running but sometimes runs correctly say for example I have tested it on fib(50000) for max=4000 but as soon as I change max=5000 it stops working. I'm breaking my head for hours but still unabled to figure out the problem.

Please tell me what might be possibly wrong with my code.

Is there any logical mistake in the code which is causing runtime error ?

Comment: Did you atleast run it in a debugger to know where it crashes? *It stops working* or *it just seg faults* is not a credible information to base our investigation.

Comment: A test case should be short and straight to the point. This code most certainly isn't.

Comment: I compiled it and run the executable in console.It shows that program has stopped working and then crashes.

Comment: @ Daniel Kozar : I tried simple test cases as well like fib(4).Problem is it just stops working and I'm not abled to understand where it is going wrong ?

Comment: @ Als : then what should I tell you which can be considered as credible information ?

Comment: @dark_shadow: I already said *"run it in a debugger to know where it crashes"* and tell us that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `mul()` function as the index `k` in the inner `for` loop can become a negative integer and `k` is used to index an array.

`k` is decremented `max - 1` times always but it is only set to `max - 1` on the first iteration of the outer `for` loop. In subsequent iterations of the outer `for` loop it is set to a value less than `max - 1` resulting in `k` becoming negative.

EDIT:

I modified the inner `for` loop:

```
for(j=max-1;j>0;j--){
    if (k < 0)
        std::cout << k << "\n";
    ...
}
```

and supplied `1` and `4` when prompted during execution and many negative values were displayed: so this is definitely one problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with larger values for `MAX` could stem from the fact that you are creating large arrays on the stack, causing a stackoverflow.

Try to dynamically allocate the objects with `new` and see if the `SIGSEGV` errors vanish.